# SQL-запрос с условием

Tags: база-данных, php, sql

Помогите сформулировать  SQL запрос + условие. Использую VAMSHOP - младший брат OS COMMERCE. Есть запрос

```
$sql = "select distinct ax.articles_id, ad.articles_name, a.articles_last_modified from " . TABLE_ARTICLES_XSELL . " ax LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_ARTICLES." a USING(articles_id) LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_ARTICLES_DESCRIPTION . " ad USING(articles_id) where ax.xsell_id = '" . (int)$_GET['products_id'] . "' and ad.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' and a.articles_status = '1' order by a.articles_last_modified";
```

Этот запрос выводит прикрепленные в админке к товарам статьи, на странице карточки товара. Статьи укладываются к разделы.

Мне нужно сформировать такой запрос, что бы выводились не все прикрепленные к товарам статьи, а только статьи, лежащие в разделе с id=2.

Я смог только вывести только ссылки на все статьи данного раздела с id=2. Вот запрос

```
$sql = "select a.articles_id, a.authors_id, a.articles_date_added, ad.articles_name, ad.articles_head_desc_tag, au.authors_name, td.topics_name, a2t.topics_id from " . TABLE_ARTICLES . " a left join " . TABLE_AUTHORS . " au on a.authors_id = au.authors_id, " . TABLE_ARTICLES_DESCRIPTION . " ad, " . TABLE_ARTICLES_TO_TOPICS . " a2t left join " . TABLE_TOPICS_DESCRIPTION . " td on a2t.topics_id = td.topics_id where (a.articles_date_available IS NULL or to_days(a.articles_date_available) <= to_days(now())) and a.articles_status = '1' and a.articles_id = a2t.articles_id and ad.articles_id = a2t.articles_id and ad.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' and td.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' and a2t.topics_id = '2' order by a.sort_order, ad.articles_name";
```

В нем много лишнего, id авторов, имена авторов. Я так понимаю что мне нужно только a2t.topics_id из этого запроса.

Comment: то что указал вывести - то и вывело, убери лишние поля

Comment: к сожалению я "немного" профан в SQL поэтому и обращаюсь... 
С алгоритмами все ок, но вот сам язык пока освоить не могу (((

Comment: Ок, давай так: скажи из каких столбцов должна выводится информация и при каком условии.

Comment: Вопрос №1. Ты вывел статьи лежащие в разделе id="2"?
Вторым запросом, только ссылки на статьи и не прикрепленные к товарам
Вопрос №2. Что есть карточка товара?
laramirra.com/Uhod-za-kozhei-45.html
Вкладка применение. в ней сей час 2й вариант запроса-ссылки на статьи из 2 раздела (1 прикрепленная к товару и одна не прикрепленная к товару)
вопрос №3. Раньше(1-ым запросом) статьи выводились на карточку товара, а потом(2-ым запросом) она выодятся не на карточку товара?
а потом(2-ым запросом) выводятся все статьи из раздела с id=2
Раньше(1-ым запросом) выводились все прикрепленные к товару статьи

Comment: Вот с таким объяснением гарантировано не помогут. Я не создавал сайт и не знаю что за карточки, админка и "не прикрепленные к товарам". Таблица- это совокупность строк и столбцов. Из каких столбцов нужно вывести информацию и с каким условием.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE a2t.topics_id = '2'", $db);
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do {
    //и вывожу их в цикле!!!
echo ("'$myrow[название поля откуда выносишь данные]'");
   
} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>

Answer (score 2):

В этом нереально разобраться! Покажу на примере.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT login,avatar FROM users WHERE gorod='Moscow'", $db); //Извлекаю из таблицы users логины и аватары тех пользователей, у которых в этой таблице поле gorod имеет значение Moscow
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do {
    //и вывожу их в цикле!!!

    echo ("<img src='$myrow[avatar]'>");
    printf("<a    href='page.php?id=%s'>%s</a><br>", $myrow['id'], $myrow['login']);

} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>
```

Если что-то не так, не судите строго)

Comment: найди в первом запросе where и после допиши a2t.topics_id = '2'

в первом же запросе к TABLE_ARTICLES_TO_TOPICS  вообще же обращения не идет, sql не узнает о чем ее просят

Answer (score 0):

прикалываешься...

```
$sql = "select a2t.topics_id from "
```

Comment: в смысле? Ребята, я ж не бум бум

Comment: Это намек на то, что нету запроса к базе должно быть примерно так $sql = mysql_query("бла бла бла")

Comment: А вот тут я с Вами поспорю. Такова структура организации. Код

 $sql            = "бла бла бла";
 $row            = 0;
 $module_content = array();
 $query          = vamDBquery($sql);
 while ($one = vam_db_fetch_array($query, true)) {
  $SEF_parameter = '';
  if (SEARCH_ENGINE_FRIENDLY_URLS == 'true')
      $SEF_parameter = '&headline=' . vam_cleanName($one['articles_name']);
 }

и т.д. Все отлично работает... дело не в том, что запрос не работает, а в том, что не могу сформировать нужный.

Comment: тогда скажи что тебе и откуда надо достать?

Comment: что бы все то же что и в первом sql запросе, но доп условие
a2t.topics_id = '2'

Comment: > Мне нужно сформировать такой запрос,
> что бы выводились не все прикрепленные
> к товарам статьи, а только статьи,
> лежащие в разделе с id=2.
> 
> Я смог только вывести только ссылки на
> все статьи данного раздела с id=2.

сложно понять что сделал, что получилось и что не получилось

Comment: найди в первом запросе where и после допиши a2t.topics_id = '2'

Comment: Первым запросом выводились как нужно статьи на карточку товара (название (ссылкой) и сам текст статьи)

Вторым запросом я смог вывести все статьи, лежащие в разделе с id=2


Мне нужно вывести на карточку товара статьи (так же название (ссылкой) и сам текст статьи) но только лежащие в разделе с id=2


т.е если бы я ляпал на паскале и не надо было делать запросы то
скажем вывод статьи делался как
writeln ('название статьи')
writeln('сама статья')

а переделал бы на

if topics_id = 2
{
writeln ('название статьи')
writeln('сама статья')
}
но а тут же sql запрос

Comment: "Вторым запросом я смог вывести все статьи, лежащие в разделе с id=2"
---->
"Мне нужно вывести на карточку товара статьи (так же название (ссылкой) и сам текст статьи) но только лежащие в разделе с id=2"

Вопрос №1. Ты вывел статьи лежащие в разделе id="2"? Вопрос №2. Что есть карточка товара? И вопрос №3. Раньше(1-ым запросом) статьи выводились на карточку товара, а потом(2-ым запросом) она выодятся не на карточку товара?

Answer (score 0):

может так:

```
 $sql = "select distinct ax.articles_id, ad.articles_name, a.articles_last_modified from " . TABLE_ARTICLES_XSELL . " ax LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_ARTICLES." a USING(articles_id) LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_ARTICLES_DESCRIPTION . " ad USING(articles_id) LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_ARTICLES_TO_TOPICS." a2t USING(articles_id) where ax.xsell_id = '" . (int)$_GET['products_id'] . "' and ad.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' and a.articles_status = '1' and a2t.topics_id = '2' order by a.articles_last_modified";
```

отличается от вашего первого запроса тем, что добавлена связка (JOIN) с таблицей `TABLE_ARTICLES_TO_TOPICS` и добавлено ограничение по полю этой таблицы topics_id = '2'